# Two style files and conflict issue in use on one page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

in my css file there is a class called .header
This class also exists in WordPress' stylesheet
as a result, both style files I call have the same class and the last one has an effect.
as a result, unwanted results occur

the solution is probably this;

```
#custom-div .header{
color:red;
}
```

but my style file is too big. It will be very difficult to add this to the beginning of the whole classes.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: What do you mean? - "but my style file is too big. It will be very difficult to add this to the beginning of the whole classes."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress Admin Dashboard > Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS >

```
#custom-div .header{
color:red !important;
}
```

This code copy paste and Published.

Answer (score 0):

1- You can change the name of your own style css code.
2- You can write the following code to the style css code in the related page.

```
#custom-div .header{
color:red !important;
}
```